# How to mount nginx.conf to container in Docker Jenkins?

Tags: docker, nginx, jenkins, docker-compose

My Nginx in docker-compose.yml:

```
...
nginx:
  image: nginx:1.19.2-alpine
  restart: always
  hostname: nginx
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
    - "9001:9001"
  depends_on:
    - minio
  volumes:
    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
  container_name: nginx
...
```

I use `docker compose up -d` in terminal and it works fine.

However, when I use `docker compose up -d` in Jenkins container, it failed to create Nginx container with this error:

```
ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed:
container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: 
container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:75: mounting 
"/var/jenkins_home/workspace/workspace/nginx.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" caused: 
mount through procfd: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file 
(or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

Does the error mean Docker want to mount the file inside Jenkins's volume so there's no `nginx.conf` to mount?

How can I mount my `nginx.conf` to my Nginx container?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you're executing `docker-compose up` from a location such your relative path ./nginx.conf is not correct.

This error is typical when docker-compose cannot find source to mount bind-volume.

Assure you're in the correct docker-compose context or try with absolute path instead of ./nginx.conf

Comment: I moved nginx.conf to the solution folder, it works fine now. Thank you.